# A question on contains() format in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

my XQuery worked perferctly, but I've always used exact match, like:

```
concat(' and title ="',$title,'"')
```

However, this is not going to work in real world, since we need to change the exact match to contain.

In this case, the title is an XML element, $title is the variable defined in the XQuery, what we want is to do not just use equal sign but test whether the title contains the substring $title.

I've played around with the syntax but still failed, could anyone help me on getting the right syntax for changing the "=" to the contains?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the concat? Are you trying to generate XQuery using XQuery? or maybe trying to generate something else using XQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
concat(' and title[contains(.,"', $title, '")]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
and title = $title
```

should become

```
and contains(title, $title)
```

But I don't understand really what you're trying to do with concat. Are you trying to generate an XQuery expression using XQuery? In that case you could change

```
concat(' and title = "', $title, '"')
```

to

```
concat(' and contains(title, "', $title, '")')
```